# Scala - class type required but T found with objectMapper

Tags: scala, generics, objectmapper

I have this method:

```
def find[T](foo: Foo) = {
  // some code
  objectmapper.readValue(stringPayload, classOf[T])
}
```

I have returned:

> scala class type required but T found objectMapper

I have read that the reason is that T is not a class type, but a type parameter.

I haven't understand how to resolve it.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, note that such code is fragile and not that common in **Scala**. From where that `objectMapper` comes from?

Comment: It comes from jackson library for json serliazation/deserialization

Comment: Do you have any reason for using a **Java** library instead of a **Scala** one?